# Page specific script remains when page changes in Next js

Tags: javascript, facebook, next.js, facebook-pixel

I'm trying to add [the Facebook Pixel script](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/implementation) to a specific page (X) of my Next js application.

I'm using [next/script](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) to add it and it is loaded properly only when page X is accessed.

However, whenever I navigate to another page after accessing page X and after the script is loaded, the script remains in the Devtools. My question is: is it supposed to work that way? Is Next.js just optimizing the script load and only executing it when page X is loaded/being accessed and nowhere else or should I explicitly tell it to remove the script if the page path is different?

I'm using the inline script approach (with the default loading strategy of next/script):

```html
<Script id="Facebook_Pixel_Code">
    {`!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');fbq('init', [OUR_FB_ID]);fbq('track', 'PageView');`}
</Script>
```

Comment: what means "the script remains in the Devtools"? does it get executed on other pages or not? you can easily check this out in the network tab.

Comment: Hi :)
The script is properly showing in the Devtools and is executed properly (fbevents call).
I was curious about the way Next js handles its behavior because a fbevents call is made when you access the page X and never makes a call again. Since I can't have access to FB tools I'm clueless if the script is working on the page X only or also in other pages (also, when I come back to page X, there's no additional call).

Comment: I have the same problem. I inject Crisp into one of our pages and when the page changes, the Crisp button remains on the page.

Comment: @StanleySathler I'm facing the same problem, my script remains and is executed on other pages as well which I really don't want it to. Were you able to solve this problem?